# Bootstrap(v4) Popover $(...).popover is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, popover, bootstrap-4

So as the title suggests, I'm having an issue with bootstrap popovers. To be specific I am getting the following error: `Uncaught TypeError: $(...).popover is not a function`.

I have seen other similar issues and have done the following:

Ensure bootstrap loads after jQuery:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/dropzone.js"></script>
<script src="/js/bootstrap.js"></script>`
```

Attempt $.noConflict:

```
$.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
$('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover(); 
});
```

Ensure the bootstrap.js contains Popover:

```
var Popover = function ($) { ... }
```

I am unsure what else to try. Any suggestions would be welcome.
Things which may be important:

- I am using a templating engine (handlebars) with external scripts loading from layout, and the popover script being on the actual body part.
- I am using Cloud 9 IDE

Answer (score -1):

include [tether.min.j](https://github.com/HubSpot/tether/blob/master/dist/js/tether.min.js)s
This should solve the problem.